# If you are running a VM, but are hardwired, doesn't it still show your ip?

Tags: virtual-machine, privacy

I have a friend who said that as long as you are running a virtual machine it's hard to get your ip. Not impossible, just harder. Say you are trying to bruteforce a password on a website through VM running Kali Linux. As soon as you start going through the payloads wouldn't your ip show up EVERYWHERE?? The only thing the VM would change is your MAC? They would still see where the attack is coming from. I could be horribly wrong, you guys would know better than I would.

Comment: His profound lack of understanding how TCP/IP works will make it quite humorous if he ever decides to script kiddie other people... _Wow Man, how did they do that?_ will be the predictable words heard...

Comment: Yeah, I feel sorry for him if he ever decides to try anything. Probably try to Ddos from cmd xD

Answer (score 4):

While running a VM as an attacker can have advantages (such as having a defined set of tools, being able to erase evidence on *your* system trivially, reduce the impact if you make any mistakes), disguising your IP is not one of them.

Running a virtual machine on your host won’t disguise you. You still have to use the same network adapter (or another network adapter plugged into the same physical host). You need an internet uplink, which will have an IP assigned (if you’re on a home network, most likely all devices share the same IPv4 using NAT, or the same IPv6 prefix). That IP is the one which will show up in the remote hosts logs, just as if you were using your host directly, instead of a virtual machine.

Comment: So if I wanted to hide my ip I would still have to use a VPN or proxies. That's what I figured.  Thanks for the fast and detailed response! Would running a VM inside of VM do anything at all if someone was trying to find where you were attacking from, or would it be pointless? And does using a WiFi card vs. being hardwired change anything at all when using VM?

Comment: Running inside a VM will not disclose your network because your modem is the part that gives you internet access and that's where your public ip comes from. Its that ip they can see, so running a vm does not change anything at all.

Comment: @SheaA. A VM in a VM is just like running a VM on the host -- except that the first VM is now the host. The same implications apply.